# Customize divi filterable portfolio module in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages, divi, divi-theme

I just wanted to ask Can someone help me how to customize divi filterable portfolio module in WordPress? The scenario is I have created three custom field through ACF plugin and I wanted to show these fields on project listing page.

I have tried to create a template from DIVI builder but when I use filterable module there is only featured image, title and categories are display.